# Accessing files outside the entry point

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am building react seed project with the structure like this:

```
project
│   package.json
│   webpack.config.js
│   .babelrc   
│
└───bin
│      app.bundle.js   
│ 
└───node_modules
|
└───public
│      index.html     
└───src
       app.jsx
```

To start the project i have setup command npm run dev which runs:

```
webpack -d --watch && ./node_modules/.bin/http-server  -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
```

It starts the server on localhost:8000 and webpack is watching for changes.

`http-server` has an entry point in ./public folder where my index.html is.

This seems to be a secure way of running server because it only have access to public folder, but then i ran into a problem when i try to include my compiled `app.bundle.js` file.

./public/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Seed project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="../bin/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i run the server i get the error that the app.bundle.js file is not found, because the server can't see anything that is over the entry point which is public folder.

Moving index.html to the root folder is not a good practice, because then it will be possible to access all the other files, which is not secure.

How should this issue be solved ?

Thanks in advance.

PS. Webpack compiles files from the src folder and creates single file in ./bin folder.

Comment: The bindle should be placed in the ./public folder. You are not making a desktop application so just forgo the ./bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is because of nodejs when you define a folder static in order to access its file like js css images etc

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

do the same for your bin file and you will access it too

```
app.use(express.static('bin'));
```